# Excel Error:Problems obtaining data while importing data from calling a Stored Procedure in MS Query

Tags: excel, stored-procedures, db2, odbc, call

I am trying to import the result of a stored procedure to Excel.
I can call the stored procedure in MS Query, but I can't import it to Excel.
I have tried different Connection type in ODBC Data Source Admin, but I see the same error.
Any thoughts?

Comment: I followed the instructions of "Get data from a SQL Server Stored Procedure into Excel automatically" http://codebyjoshua.blogspot.com/2012/01/get-data-from-sql-server-stored.html

Comment: Can you kindly provide the error that you are getting and the Connection type you are using?

Comment: I defined an SQL Stored procedure in IBM Data Studio. I deplyed it and I can run it. I am also able to call it in MS Query, but the problem occurs when I try to import the result to Excel to create a Pivot table report! The error is :" Problems obtaining data"                                                                       
 
Connection types that I tried: ODBC Access mode, Call allowed and Limit to Read/Call(Select and Call statements allowed)

Comment: Can you try the solution referenced in this article: http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/problems-obtaining-data-t505756.html Try re-registering DAO360.dll by running
`egsvr32 "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Dao\dao360.dll"`